# STM32 unable to be read

Tags: stm32, erase, stm32f4

I was halfway through flashing this STM32F411 when it somehow disconnected. And because of that it seems to be unable to be read even through STM32CubeProgrammer. I've searched a lot of stuff trying to fix this issue but the results don't seem relevant to me.

Initially I tried to connect it to STM32CubeProgrammer to try and erase it before I download the firmware onto it.

So when I connect the board to my laptop while in DFU mode and connect it through STM32CubeProgrammer, it can't read it and the output goes as follows:

```
  19:23:58:077 : UPLOADING ...
  19:23:58:077 :   Size          : 1024 Bytes
  19:23:58:077 :   Address       : 0x8000000
  19:23:58:077 : Read progress:
  19:23:58:077 : Status: 14, State: 10
  19:23:58:078 : sending a clear status request
  19:23:58:078 : libusb control transfer error [-9] : LIBUSB_ERROR_PIPE  
  19:23:58:078 : sending a clear status request
  19:23:58:078 : libusb control transfer error [-9] : LIBUSB_ERROR_PIPE  
  19:23:58:078 : sending a clear status request
  19:23:58:078 : libusb control transfer error [-9] : LIBUSB_ERROR_PIPE  
  19:23:58:078 : sending a clear status request
  19:23:58:078 : libusb control transfer error [-9] : LIBUSB_ERROR_PIPE  
  19:23:58:078 : sending a clear status request
  19:23:58:078 : libusb control transfer error [-9] : LIBUSB_ERROR_PIPE  
  19:23:58:078 : sending a clear status request
  19:23:58:079 : libusb control transfer error [-9] : LIBUSB_ERROR_PIPE  
  19:23:58:079 : sending a clear status request
  19:23:58:079 : libusb control transfer error [-9] : LIBUSB_ERROR_PIPE  
  19:23:58:079 : sending a clear status request
  19:23:58:079 : libusb control transfer error [-9] : LIBUSB_ERROR_PIPE  
  19:23:58:079 : sending a clear status request
  19:23:58:081 : libusb control transfer error [-9] : LIBUSB_ERROR_PIPE  
  19:23:58:081 : sending a clear status request
  19:23:58:083 : libusb control transfer error [-9] : LIBUSB_ERROR_PIPE  
  19:23:58:083 : unable to switch the device to dfuIDLE/dfuDNLOAD_IDLE state
  19:23:58:083 : Error: Data read failed
```

And under the device memory tab, there is no table to be displayed.

Nonetheless I tried erasing it anyway and it didn't work:

```
  19:31:38:702 : MASS ERASE ... 
  19:31:38:703 : Status: 14, State: 10
  19:31:38:703 : sending a clear status request
  19:31:38:704 : libusb control transfer error [-9] : LIBUSB_ERROR_PIPE  
  19:31:38:704 : sending a clear status request
  19:31:38:704 : libusb control transfer error [-9] : LIBUSB_ERROR_PIPE  
  19:31:38:704 : sending a clear status request
  19:31:38:705 : libusb control transfer error [-9] : LIBUSB_ERROR_PIPE  
  19:31:38:705 : sending a clear status request
  19:31:38:705 : libusb control transfer error [-9] : LIBUSB_ERROR_PIPE  
  19:31:38:705 : sending a clear status request
  19:31:38:706 : libusb control transfer error [-9] : LIBUSB_ERROR_PIPE  
  19:31:38:706 : sending a clear status request
  19:31:38:706 : libusb control transfer error [-9] : LIBUSB_ERROR_PIPE  
  19:31:38:706 : sending a clear status request
  19:31:38:707 : libusb control transfer error [-9] : LIBUSB_ERROR_PIPE  
  19:31:38:707 : sending a clear status request
  19:31:38:707 : libusb control transfer error [-9] : LIBUSB_ERROR_PIPE  
  19:31:38:707 : sending a clear status request
  19:31:38:708 : libusb control transfer error [-9] : LIBUSB_ERROR_PIPE  
  19:31:38:708 : sending a clear status request
  19:31:38:708 : libusb control transfer error [-9] : LIBUSB_ERROR_PIPE  
  19:31:38:709 : unable to switch the device to dfuIDLE/dfuDNLOAD_IDLE state
  19:31:38:709 : Error: Mass erase operation failed.Please verify flash protection
```

I am also completely unable to access the Option Bytes or MCU Core tabs in STM32CubeProgrammer.
How I should go about solving this problem?

Edit:

some extra details if you do need them
It's interesting to take note that when I plug in the device normally the activity lights do not light up, and my computer wouldn't register when I plug it in.

Comment: Have you tried to **connect under reset** in STM32CubeProgrammer?

Comment: connect under reset in STM32CubeProgrammer? well if you're talking about using ST-LINK Util, i don't have anything like that unfortunately. how would connect under reset help though?

Comment: Connect under reset work when connected using SWD. It narurally do not work when running in DFU/bootloader mode.